# Use arrow keys in the middle of command

Tags: bash, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts

I type 3 commands in my terminal, one after another:

```
command1
command2
command3
```

If I use the up arrow key on my keyboard, I can access the previous commands. Suppose I want to use those commands in a new command. For example, the fourth command might look like this `command1 && command2 | command3`, How can I use shortkeys (e.g. up arrow key) to access previous commands when I'm in the middle of a new command?

These commands are very long, what's the fastest way to write the fourth command?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I’m not sure it can be done with arrow keys, but you can use history shortcuts:

```
!-3 && !-2 | !-1
```

`!-3` will be replaced by the third-last command, `!-2` the second-last, and `!-1` the last.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Emacs-style line editing enabled in `bash`, then the arrow-key method is possible.

Building the command left-to-right is long-ish, but works:

<kbd>Up</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd><kbd>Up</kbd> ... (to reveal `command1`)

<kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd> ... (to copy but not cut `command1`)

<kbd>Down</kbd> ... (to reveal `command2`)

<kbd>Home</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd>
<kbd>Space</kbd>
<kbd>&</kbd>
<kbd>&</kbd>
<kbd>Space</kbd> ... ( to paste `command1 &&`  in front of `command2`)

<kbd>End</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> ... (to cut `command1 && command2`)

<kbd>Down</kbd> ... (to reveal `command3`)

<kbd>Home</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd>
<kbd>Space</kbd>
<kbd>|</kbd>
<kbd>Space</kbd> ... (to paste `command1 && command2 |`  in front of `command3`)

Slightly fewer keystrokes are required to build the command from right to left:

<kbd>Up</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> ... (to reveal and cut `command3`)

<kbd>Up</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>|</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-U</kbd> ... (to cut `command2 | command3`)

<kbd>Up</kbd>
<kbd>Space</kbd>
<kbd>&</kbd>
<kbd>&</kbd>
<kbd>Space</kbd>
<kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd> ... (to reveal `command1` and then append  `&& command2 | command3`)